# How select data from select statement from another database?

Tags: sql-server

This is my query.

```
select * 
from dbase1.dbo.profile 
where dbase1.dbo.profile.id IN (select * from dbase2.dbo.profile where country='philippines');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's on the same server, you can just reference database name.

```
 SELECT * FROM dbase1.dbo.profile a INNER JOIN dbase2.dbo.profile b
 ON a.id = b.id
 WHERE b.country = 'Philippines'
```

The reason your query is failing is because of this part

```
 where dbase1.dbo.profile.id IN (select * from dbase2.dbo.profile....
```

You are comparing dbase1.dbo.profile.id with ALL columns on dbase2.dbo.profile,
your query would work if you change it to

```
   where dbase1.dbo.profile.id IN (select id from dbase2.dbo.profile....
```

So that your query only compares one column to another column

This assumes that dbase2.dbo.profile also has a column named ID and it's the one column that you are referencing

Comment: Thanks sir. problem solve. ^_^